# Error while logging into ubuntu Server

Tags: server

I am getting this error while logging into my ubuntu server as soon as i type in the command

wsl -d Ubuntu-22.04 i get this error.

```
<3>WSL (9) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:577: execvpe SHELL failed 2

<3>WSL (15) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:586: Create process not expected to return
```

Comment: Does it literally say `SHELL`? Did you recently attempt to change the default user's login shell (by using `chsh`, or editing the `/etc/passwd` file for example)?